# Is there any well-defined way to programmatically create a user?

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I'm researching YouTube for backing a video system of ours. We have many clients and if clients were to use the system they would likely want their own accounts. Observing the YouTube API it does not appear I can manipulate user information. Is it possible to programmatically create users for YouTube via another Google API or the Youtube API itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, clients will have to create accounts manually. Programmatic account creation would be ripe for abuse.